# When to impose parameter restriction in max. likelihood ex-ante or ex-post?

Tags: r, estimation, optimization

I am estimating the following model
$$ y = g(x_1\beta_1 + x_2\beta_2) + u$$

where $g()$ is some function and $u$ is a random disturbance. I want to impose the restriction that the first coefficient is $\beta_1=1$. And I am estimating the other parameter with max likelihood.

What is the best way to do it? Should I impose the restriction while optimizing or rather I first find the optimum and then normalize everything by dividing coefficients by the estimated $\hat \beta_1$?

Here is a minimal example in R.

```
n <- 100
x1 <- runif(100)
x2 <- runif(100)
x3 <- runif(100)
x <- cbind(x1, x2, x3)
y <- ifelse(x1 + x2 + x3 + rnorm(n) >0 , 1, 0) 
fn <- function(b, x, y) {
  xB <- x %*% b
  xB <- ifelse(xB <= 0.01, 0.01, 1)
  xB <- ifelse(xB >= 1, 0.99, 1)
  sum(y * log(xB) + (1-y) * log (1- xB))
}
est <- optim(par=runif(ncol(x)), fn, x=x, y=y)
est$par / est$par[1]
```

Should I rather impose `b[1]=1` in the `fn` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use your approach `b[1]=1` in the `fn`, this is because we are using knowledge to simplify the objective function,  and not making the problem more complex and adding constraints.

A more obvious example: suppose in optimization setting, you have $100$ parameters to tune, but you already know the exact value of $99$ of them.

Should you build a problem with $1$ parameter to optimize, or make a high dimensional problem with many constraints?

BTW, in many solvers, the first step on constrained optimization is trying to work with the constraints and simplify the problem (combine constraints, detect conflicting constraints, etc.). So, it may not matter for both ways. But I feel more in control with the first approach.